Are all compact simple Lie groups subgroups of special unitary groups?
From my understanding, a compact Lie group has Hermitian generators and a semi-simple Lie group has traceless generators. Therefore it seems that a compact simple Lie group has traceless Hermitian generators. However traceless Hermitian generators generate elements of the special unitary group. This leads to my question: whether all compact simple Lie groups are subgroups of special unitary groups?

Unless I’m mistaken, any nontrivial compact connected Lie group $G$ has nontrivial finite-dimensional representations – which can be made unitary by choosing a Hermitian metric (by averaging over $G$).

Yes. This follows from the Peter-Weyl theorem, which implies that every compact Lie group $G$ (not necessarily simple, semisimple, or even connected) has a faithful f.d. unitary representation $V$, hence embeds as a closed subgroup of some unitary group $U(n)$. If $G$ is also simple, then its elements necessarily have determinant $1$ inside $U(n)$, so it embeds as a closed subgroup of $SU(n)$.
You already need to know that compact Lie groups have faithful f.d. unitary representations in order to assert that they "have Hermitian generators." This fact is not obvious and requires proof; it is not true, for example, that noncompact Lie groups have faithful f.d. representations, e.g. the metaplectic group does not.
OTOH, your use of language suggests you are a physicist, and for every compact Lie group occurring in physics you can just explicitly write down a faithful f.d. unitary representation. Also in physics it appears to be common to ignore the difference between Lie groups and Lie algebras; if you're happy to have a faithful unitary representation of the Lie algebra, or equivalently an embedding $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{su}(n)$, then a much easier argument is available: namely, you can take the adjoint representation, which for simple $\mathfrak{g}$ is always faithful, and for compact simple $\mathfrak{g}$ can be made unitary by averaging an inner product. This embeds $\mathfrak{g}$ into $\mathfrak{su}(\dim \mathfrak{g})$.
The reason this isn't an answer to the Lie group version of the question is that the kernel of the adjoint representation of $G$ always includes the center of $G$; for example the adjoint representation of $SU(n)$ has kernel the central $\mathbb{Z}/n$. So it is rarely faithful, but if $G$ is compact simple it has discrete kernel so is "almost faithful" (and the corresponding Lie algebra representation is faithful).

worth mentioning $U(n)\hookrightarrow  SU(n+1)$
